# github API, fork a repo

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the github API with python, but got stuck when wanting to fork a repo.
My script so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import getpass
from restkit import Resource, BasicAuth, request
from socketpool import ConnectionPool

user= raw_input( "Github user:" )

password=getpass.getpass()
auth=BasicAuth(user, password)

authreqdata = { "scopes": [ "public_repo" ], "note": "admin script" }

resource = Resource('https://api.github.com/authorizations', filters=[auth])
response = resource.post(headers={ "Content-Type": "application/json" },         payload=json.dumps(authreqdata))
token = json.loads(response.body_string())['token']

print token
```

I got the security token, but failed miserably trying to fork a repo.

Could you help me with that?

THanks in advance!

Comment: What is your repo-forking code (even if it doesn't work)?

Comment: resource = Resource('https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/fork')
headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
headers['Authorization'] = 'token %s' % token
response = resource.post(headers = headers)
forks = json.loads(response.body_string())


I actually never specify the actual repo, which might be the problem